# Сохранение файлов и папок после удаления приложения

Tags: android

Обычно при удалении приложения удаляются все созданные им папки и файлы. Но, это не всегда удобно.

Например, пользователю нужно сохранить те данные, которые он накопил во время работы с программой.

Вопрос. В какую папку или каким способом необходимо сохранять файлы в Android, чтобы они не удалялись вместе с приложением?

Comment: Перед удалением скопировать нужное.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удаляются не все файлы, созданные приложением, а только те, что записаны в приватных папках (через контекст).
Чтобы файлы оставались после удаления приложения пишите их в общедоступную память. Класс [`Environment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) и руководство: [Save a file on external storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage) помогут.

Или через [Платформу доступа к хранилищу (Storage Access Framework)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider?hl=RU)